# Updating batch of rows depending on last row of previous batch

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have following data -

```
create table #Test(
    Id int
    ,JobNo int
)

insert into #Test
values 
(1,100) ,(2,100)
,(3,101),(4,104)
,(5,105),(6,106)
```

My requirement is that I need to update batch of rows sequentially. Say batch size here is 2, then for rows between Id 3 to 4, I need to take the JobId value of 100 from first batch and increment it to 1. Likewise for rows between Id 5-6, I need to update JobId as 102.

Expected Output is -

```
Id,JobId
1,100
2,100
3,101
4,101
5,102
6,102
```

I am able to achieve this using while loop and counter but am just wondering if it can be done via partitioning and self-joins. I am not able to get the right partitioning criteria to divide them into equal batches. Even if I partition I don't know how to proceed with sequentially add up the values. A recursive CTE perhaps? Just pondering.

Comment: Can batch size be dynamic or does it remain 2?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE t_curr
SET JobNo = ISNULL(t_prev.JobNo + ((t_curr.Id - 1) / @batchSize), t_curr.JobNo)
FROM #Test t_curr
JOIN #Test t_prev ON t_prev.Id = t_curr.Id - @batchSize
```

Let me know if it is not something you need.

Comment: Thanks Chaos for reply. It is not returning the right result. The rows with Id's 5 and 6 are having old values i.e. 103 and 106. It should have been 102 for both. I am just trying to figure out logic you used. Batch size would be dynamic as you have guessed by keeping it as param.

Comment: It's working just fine for me. I tried with your input. Are you sure you're not doing anything after you used this update statement?

Comment: Yes, I tried with same input. The last two rows aren't getting updated. Here is a link - https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6324BEB801DC478A!1265&authkey=!AGmNTvB3RYHFnHI&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: link not reachable to me.

Comment: Could you try this link - https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/VnWRQyYVh5f92zwT6T_qMtMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink  and check?

Comment: Even this link is not visible to me sorry

Comment: Hmm..well I don't know how else to tell. I have executed the script as is with the update script you have provided, the last two rows aren't getting updated.